# How do i reference a variable from another method?

Tags: minecraft

So I'm attempting to make a Minecraft chat plugin, here is my code.

```
public class ChatListener implements Listener {
    public static String displayName;
    void name(Player event) {
        ChatListener.displayName =  event.getDisplayName();

    }

    @EventHandler
    public static void (AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
        final String message = "[" + displayName + "]" + e.getMessage();
        e.setMessage(message);
    }
}
```

I always seem to be getting null as displayName in `final String message = "[" + displayName + "]" + e.getMessage();`

and since I may not have 2 parameters in a variable, how am I supposed to get the display name via `getDisplayName()`?

Comment: You must call `name` before your second method is called. You also forgot to give us it's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `AsyncPlayerChatEvent`([Spring Javadocs](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/player/AsyncPlayerChatEvent.html)) you'll see that you can access a `Player` object  with it, therefore you don't need to store it in a static variable.

```
public class ChatListener implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerAsyncChatEvent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
        String displayName = e.getPlayer().getDisplayName(;

        final String message = "[" + displayName + "]" + e.getMessage();
        e.setMessage(message);
    }

}
```

As you described your problem, this should solve your issue.